# modo de dar echo tipo laravel

Tags: php

Recentemente comecei a utilizar o *Laravel* e achei a função `{{}}` muito útil, pois mesmo que seja um *JavaScript*, ela não ativa, diferente do `echo` no *PHP*.

Queria saber se tem como fazer a mesma coisa no *PHP*

**Exemplo a básico:**

```
<?php
echo "<script> alert(\"Hello! I am an alert box!!\");</script>";
?>
```

Ele vai executar o *JavaScript*, porém no *Laravel* com o `{{}}` ele vai mostrar o que esta escrito, mas sem executar o *JavaScript*.

Comment: é porque no `{{}}` é caso você queira mostrar uma variável que vem do controller. Ex: `{{ $variavel }}` se nao me engano, echo também funciona no Laravel. Agora você consegue executar dentro de um arquivo blade.php um javascript normal

Comment: Utilize a função `htmlentities` antes do `echo`.

Comment: Explica melhor isso aí? Ficou meio confuso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O blade do Laravel transforma `{{ }}` numa função [interna chamada `e()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/Concerns/CompilesEchos.php#L89), que vem de *escape*.

O código [dessa função `e()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php#L564-L580) é o seguinte:

```
function e($value, $doubleEncode = true)
{
    if ($value instanceof Htmlable) {
        return $value->toHtml();
    }
    return htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', $doubleEncode);
}
```

Ou seja, usar `htmlspecialchars` resulta em algo parecido.

O objetivo para se fazer isso é evitar ataques onde se injeta códigos para produzir algo inesperado na aplicação, como Javascripts maliciosos.

Validar as entradas e saídas do seu código, principalmente os lugares onde o usuário tem o poder de inserir ou editar dados, é algo que pode passar desapercebido mas é muito importante para a segurança.